# Increase size of sparsebundle for TimeMachine

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, sparsebundle

I am using a sparsebundle store on a linux server. It worked well until today.

Today Time Machine tells me that the size of the sparsebundle (500gb) is not sufficient. So I use `hdiutil` command for increasing the size of the sparsebundle: `hdiutil resize -size 600G xxx.sparsebundle`. The command works fine but Time Machine seems to not see the increase of the size of the sparsebundle (it only sees that the size is 500gb and so it can't continue to backup).

Do you have any idea for solving this issue?

NB:

- the sparsebundle is encrypted
- Time Machine mounts automatically the sparsebundle (linux server configured with afp and netatalk).

Version:

- ProductName: Mac OS X
- ProductVersion:  10.10.1
- BuildVersion:    14B25

Comment: After you resized the bundle, did you go to the Mac doing the backups and remove all backup destinations in the system preferences? At that point, I'd reboot the Mac and then set up Time Machine with the new mount. If you did some other setup, please edit that into the question.

Comment: @bmike I just tested your proposal but nothing changed... The result is the same.

Comment: @bmike You say "remove all backup destinations in the system preferences". Do you mean in Time Machine or in another place?

Comment: Yes - On 10.10 the text is "Add or Remove Backup Disk..." or "Select Disk" if you have but one destination selected. Once the pref is "clean" you will be greeted with text "Select Backup Disk..." and Finder may prompt you to select disks as they mount. Also, edit in what `sw_vers` shows from terminal on your Mac.

Comment: Ok I did this but nothing change... It's really weird because when I display the content of the sparsebundle, I see in the file `Info.plist` the line size and the 600gb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

For obtaining AFP on linux server, it is possible to specify a size limit of the AFP volume in `/usr/local/etc/afp.conf` using keyword `vol size limit`. Just check if this value is not too low!!

In my case, I upgrade `netatalk` from the default ubuntu package (version 2.2) to the up to date version (3.1.7). During this upgrade I remembered that I have specified a low size limit....

See :

- http://www.netafp.com/downloads/
- http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/
- http://outcoldman.com/en/archive/2014/11/09/ubuntu-as-home-server-part-3-afp-server/

Answer (score 7):

> 6. Double-click the sparse bundle to mount the Time Machine Backups or Backup of <computer name> partition (but don’t select it). That may take a moment.
> 7. Select the sparse bundle again, and click the Partition tab towards the top of the
>      window.
>
>    [image]
> 8. Type the desired size in the space provided, or, in the diagram that appears, drag the lower right corner of the partition all the way to the bottom to fill the volume, or drag it upwards to shrink it, click Apply and confirm.
> 9. As part of the process, Disk Utility will do a verification of the data in the partition, so it may take quite a while. You can see the log of what it's doing by selecting Window > Show Log in the menubar.
> 10. When done, and you quit Disk Utility, you may get an Operations still in progress message. As long as the log says "Partition Complete," it's done, so click Close.
> 11. Eject the sparse bundle before starting the next backup.

Source: [http://pondini.org/TM/A8.html](https://www.baligu.com/pondini/TM/A8.html)

Comment: My guess exactly as to what might be causing it. Pondini is so awesome for advanced Time Machine users...

Comment: I already followed this process but no success...